# Compatible HVAC filter

Tags: hvac, central-air, air-filter

I need to replace the filter in my HVAC system. What I found at the air handler in the attic is shown in the picture. It says Aprilaire Model 2200 media air cleaner. My questions are:

1. Is it the filter holder with a filter inside that needs to be replaced or is the whole thing a filter in and of itself and the whole thing needs to be replaced?
2. Is Modeel 2200 sufficient for compatibility? For instance, is [This Product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040VU3XO) compatible?

Thank you!
 [image]

Comment: My Space-Gard 2200 takes the Aprilaire 201 expandable media, and that is what we have always bought, but maybe the 213 would fit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Aprilaire 2200 is what you need to replace the filter.

These air filters can be replaced one of two ways:

1. Replace the filter paper itself using the existing frame. The paper filter will accordion open to fit in the frame. This option is what the product you listed will do.
2. Remove the (probably plastic) frame and use a box-style filter to replace it. This stay has the accordion filter in a cardboard frame that you can insert into the furnace then close up. If you do this, just keep the plastic frame so you can go back to method 1 if you want.

Answer (score 1):

@kponz's answer is correct with one caveat - when you buy aftermarket filters or filter inserts/cartridges/media, sometimes the aftermarket part does not always fit properly 100%.

I believe they sell the 2200 and 2400 at Home Depot too. *(I have the same filter on my rental).  I'm not recommending you buy at Home Depot, just making sure you know to read the comments on Amazon or where ever and "buyer beware"

The one you listed has solid review so it looks good.The price is maybe on the high side (I think I usually spend like $32)

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally obvious how to go about putting in the media, and it takes a few times to make the procedure "automatic". I have done ours for the 26 years our unit has been in service and done it many times on another unit.

Ours has a set of plastic combs that separate the folds. Be careful how these are removed--it is easy to break the tabs at the ends. Ours are intact after 26 years, but another household near us with the same filter unit has *all* the tabs broken off. The trick is to pry it off with the thumb and fingers of *one* hand so the end tab is not stressed at an angle.

There are two slightly different types of holder for the filter media and this other household has the other type from ours, but it takes the same media. There are diagrams on the the box that the media comes in.